# The posted video is/was about something. Is or Was?

Tags: word-choice, past-tense, present-tense

I've been attending online classes (recorded) on a daily basis and once the uploaded video wasn't on the topic as per the timetable. I texted my teacher a question similar to this:

*Shouldn't today's class be on matrices?*

followed by

*The video posted **was** trigonometry part 1*

(The video hadn't been taken down.) 
Is this sentence wrong?
Is it "is" or "was"?

Comment: Is the video still posted, or has it been taken down? I suggests editing your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your first question to your teacher mentions "today's" video, it sounds like the video is still posted and you are wondering whether it is a mistake and, most important, whether the material you are supposed to be viewing is actually available.

So we're still in the present. I would therefore suggest "The video posted is..." The other choice is not grammatically wrong, but it's clearer to use "is".